# Add corner radius to hexagon shape

Tags: android

I have this hexagon that is a shape and I want to add corner radius:

**Hexagon**

```
 <vector
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:height="300dp"
         android:width="300dp"
         android:viewportWidth="300"
         android:viewportHeight="300">

    <path
         android:fillColor="#c3c3c3"
         android:strokeColor="#F29E9E9E"
         android:strokeAlpha=".5"
         android:strokeWidth="6"
         android:pathData="M150,4L294,75 294,225 150,296 4,225 4,75Z"
      />

   </vector>
```

This is what I have:

[image]

How can I add corner radius to this hexagon? I would like to add a curve to what is enclosed in the blue circles

Comment: You need to edit your vector path.

Comment: I found a library for this. https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Comment: @TheWanderer I know i have to edit my vector path but what I should add to get what I want?

Comment: @AshishKudale Yes I know but it doesn't help me for what I need.

Comment: Where did you get your vector ?

Comment: @JcDecary I created it myself

Comment: i don't know the tool that you use to create it but with Inkscape it's easy to add round corner

Comment: @JCDecary I use this: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_path

Comment: you can download inkscape it's free and follow this tutorial, to create your shape :https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/shapes/tutorial-shapes.html after you can transform your SVG into path with android studio